# Unable to refresh jQueryMobile lists using jQueryTemplate

Tags: refresh, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I'm unable to refresh lists in [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com).

`$('ul').listview('refresh');`

The code above generates the following error:

> uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're not calling `refresh();` until the DOM is loaded `$(document).ready()` ensures this. Lists are not initialized until the DOM has finished loading and so you'd be calling refresh on something that is not initialized explaining your error.